# Change day number color on click - not background

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to change the day number color when I click in any day in full calendar. I'm trying to show that the day clicked is activated.

I tried to use the recommended textColor, color, borderColor and backgroundColor but only the last one works.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
                $(this).css('textColor', 'red');
            },
```

Thank you.

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: I'm not using any plugin, just imported full calendar inside a Cordova app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    dayClick: function (date) {
                        var moment = date.toDate();
                        MyDateString = moment.getFullYear() + '-'
                                + ('0' + (moment.getMonth() +1) ).slice(-2)
                                + "-" +('0' + moment.getDate()).slice(-2);
                        $('[data-date='+MyDateString+']').css({"color": "red", "backgroundColor": "yellow", "borderBottom": "5px solid #ccc"});
                    }
                });
```

**Explanation:**

```
var moment = date.toDate();
```

This changes the date string to javascript date object

```
MyDateString = moment.getFullYear() + '-'
                                    + ('0' + (moment.getMonth() +1) ).slice(-2)
                                    + "-" +('0' + moment.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

This code changes date format to 2016-07-29

```
$('[data-date='+MyDateString+']').css({"color": "red", "backgroundColor": "yellow", "borderBottom": "5px solid #ccc"});
```

This check in our html where attribute data-date="2016-07-29" and applies the style accordingly

Hope this helps

Comment: Amazing Ali Mehdi, I just added moment.getDate() +1 because was activating yesterday on click.