# In my VUE application "this" keyword does select a DOM object

Tags: jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar, vue-component

I am writing a VUE.js and FullCalendar application in my Calendar.vue component I run into a problem, the this keyword will not select an element. The template of the component looks like this:

```
    <template>
       <div id="calendar" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @event-created="eventCreated" :config="config">
          <button id="red" v-on:click="time">time</button>
          <full-calendar id="target" ref="calendarC" :navLinks="true" :event-sources="eventSources" @event-selected="eventSelected" @day-click="click"@event-created="eventCreated" :config="config"></full-calendar>  
       </div>
   </template>
```

And the function where my "this" keyword is not working is here:

```
    click: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
       $("#red").css('background-color', 'red'); //here the jQuery works
       $(this.selected).css('background-color', 'red');//here nothing happens
    }
```

So when I click on an element in my calendar the button with the id red turns red which lets me know jQuery is working properly. But the element I click on does not turn red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Vue.js doesn't have a built-in concept of a 'selected' element. You may be better off by using the `date` returned by the `day-click` event to figure out what the CSS selector is, and then using that to set the background-color. See below for some untested code based on the answer to a related SO question:

```
click: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
    $("#red").css('background-color', 'red');

    var moment = date.toDate();
    MyDateString = moment.getFullYear() + '-'
                   + ('0' + (moment.getMonth() + 1) ).slice(-2)
                   + "-" +('0' + moment.getDate()).slice(-2);
    $('[data-date='+MyDateString+']').css({'background-color', 'red'});
}
```

Source: [Change day number color on click - not background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38658541/4115031)